# How open nested screen session with screen command linux

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to open multiple sessions in one main session with a screen command, and I can do that after opening the main session and then  press on the keyboard (CTRL + A + c) but I don't want this way I want to do this using the command line only because I create a script to open the main session with multiple sub-session, so how can I achieve this. And thanks in advance :)

Comment: CTRL+A+C creates a new window, not a new screen session.By "sub-session", do you mean a full screen session within another screen session, or just a shell within a screen session? (BTW, I've found that tmux is more powerful and versatile than screen, and easier to operate from the command line. If you haven't gotten very comfortable with screen yet, you might consider switching.)

Comment: Yeah CTRL+A+C create a new window inside session then it became nested session, righ?, I mean when I need used nest session manually I open one screen session after that I create session with  CTRL+A+C to get benefit of shortcut keys options with nested sesion.
tmux? Never heard about it before, right now I need screen :D
@KeithThompson thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+A+C doesn't create a new `screen` session. It creates a new window within the current session.

(With a little environment trickery, you could create a nested screen session within an existing screen session, where the outer screen session and the inner screen session could each have multiple windows, but that's probably not what you want to do.)

Each window within a `screen` session runs a command. By default, that command is your login shell. Thus you can have multiple shell processes running simultaneously and switch between them.

From any of those shells, you can create a new window under the current `screen` session using the `screen` command.  It uses the `$STY` environment variable to recognize that it's inside an existing session, which tells it to create a new window rather than starting a new session. You could also type, for example, `screen vi` to launch a new window running the `vi` editor.

All this is covered in the `screen` documentation (`info screen` or `man screen`).

(Personally, I used `screen` for a long time, but then switched to `tmux`, which I find to be more flexible, more powerful, and easier to control from the command line. If you haven't invested a lot of time learning `screen`, you might consider switching. Or not; it's up to you, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using by by putting the following in your ~/.screenrc (or using a custom .screenrc file):

```
$ cat ~/tmp/screenrc_custom
...
<content of ~/.screenrc>
...
screen -t csh 0
screen -t csh 1
screen -t csh 2

$ screen -c ~/tmp/screenrc_custom
```